# How can I place a text and a form next to each other?

Tags: html, css

please I need your help. I would like to place the text and the contact form next to each other. Please see the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD9DP.jpg

Here's is the code:
https://ufile.io/2myru

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  place the text
</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 place the contact form
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion